# Update function with local variable

Tags: r, function

How can I update a function using the value of an assigned variable? This would be useful for updating functions in a `for` loop.

```
t <- 10
fn <- function(x) return(x + t)
```

**Call**

```
function(x) return(x + t)
```

**Desired output**

```
function(x) return(x + 10)
```

**Attempt**

I tried using `body()` and `expression()` but with no luck.

```
body(fn) <- expression(x + t)
```

Update: I should mention I need the function to update so I can integrate it using the `integrate()` function.

Comment: Do you essentially want `t` to evaluate to `10` within the function definition?

Comment: @zack I want the function to change to 10 using the local variable `t`

Comment: `body(fn)[[2]] <- substitute(x + t, list(t = t))`

Comment: @RichScriven Yes, that's it! THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rich Scriven, this works:

```
body(fn)[[2]] <- substitute(x + t, list(t = t))
```

**Call**

```
> fn
> function (x) 
> return(x + 10)
> fn(1)
> 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making a closure instead, that is a function that returns a function (with an associated environment, where `t` is found in this case):

```
fn <- function(t) function(x) x + t

fn(10)    
# function(x) x + t
# <bytecode: 0x02aa2a74>
# <environment: 0x177baf80>

fn(10)(32)    
# [1] 42
```

Example use in a `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:3) print(fn(i)(7))

# [1] 8
# [1] 9
# [1] 10
```